# Getting this error in sqlplus -- ORA-01855: AM/A.M. or PM/P.M. required

Tags: sql, oracle

I am executing this query and getting this error. Please help.

```
SQL> select to_timestamp((sysdate-1)||'01.00.00.000000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF PM') from dual;
```

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-01855: AM/A.M. or PM/P.M. required

Comment: Removed. Can you please help me out of this?

Comment: Sorry, don't know Oracle that well.

Comment: What do you like to get? Yesterday 01:00:00.00?

Comment: Try `SELECT TO_CHAR(cast(TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP) + INTERVAL '1' HOUR as timestamp), 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF PM') FROM dual;`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Minor bug: your query returns today's date, whereas the OP's returns yesterday's date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `sysdate` without explicit casting, you assume that you NLS settings give a date in format `'DD-MON-RR'`.
To build a safer query, use explicit conversion, with format mask:

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> select to_timestamp(to_char(sysdate-1,'DD-MON-RR' ) ||' 01.00.00.000000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF PM') from dual;

TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1,'DD-MON-RR')||'01.00.00.000000000PM','DD-MON
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
15-SET-16 13:00:00,000000000

SQL>
```

Comment: This query runs fine in sql developer. I want to execute this in sqlplus. In sqlplus window, it throws error;

Comment: thanx alot.. it works... sorry for the previous comment.... I checked it correctly... it is working ..many thanks

Comment: @Rahul If Aleksej's answer solved your problem, please accept it (using the checkmark button next to it)